# Mark email messages received with delay

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, vba

For many reasons an email message can be hold up in mailservers for several hours or even days.

I wanted to create a rule that assigns a given category to messages received with a delay greater than **x** minutes, but that's not doable with outlook rules.
I'm guessing that something in the line of that can be achieved with a VBA macro or a Powershell script, maybe comparing the message headers date with the inbox date.

I'm struggling to find a solution and I'm not a programming expert, so any help will be highly appreciated.

I'm using Outlook 2016 with an office365 account on Windows10.

Comment: Not sure this is even possible. Can you at least see in the headers vs current time that there is a delay?

Comment: @LPChip The headers have several `Received:` lines with info about each server the message went trough. I can see the delay there (see this article https://mail.aegee.org/delays/headers.html ). It should be possible to compare date and time on the first record with the date and time of the last record.

Comment: that's going to make things hard because some mails only have one received header, where others may have multiple, and then the delay can vary too. Technically it is possible, but I don't know how.

Comment: But it might be helpful if you explain why you want to do this. There may be a more straightforward answer here that is easy to implement.

Comment: Well, I want to do this because the mailserver of my client is very unstable, but is the only way I have to receive alarms about his system (wich I'm monitoring). I want to discard alarms I'm receiving now, but were triggered 2-3 days ago.
Regarding the Received header, I guess if you compare the first record with the current time will do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is doable with Outlook rule and **run a script** action (you may need to use the [EnableUnsafeClientMailRules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191893/) registry value to unlock it).

In a VBA script that created Outlook rule will fire, use MailItem's [SentOn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senton) and [ReceivedTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) properties to calculate a delay. After that use the [Categories](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.categories) property to assign a required category.